# How to catch color fault in WriteableBitmapEx GetColor WP7

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-phone-7, writeablebitmap

I just read any image and could not get the correct colors.

I've tried several images with several formats. 
Please advice how to receive the correct colors in `WriteableBitmap.GetPixels()`

In the following example, I just `cloned the image` by reading out the source pixel by pixel and putting this pixel to the new writeablebitmap on same position. Like cloning.

[image: WriteableBitmap fault]

Answer (score 0):

There is a fault in the Writeablebitmap Ex compiled / downloadable version 1.0.2 (others version until V 1.0.5 untested). By using the sourcecode of [writeablebitmapex](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/95925) Version 1.0.5, the method works as it should.

[image: Working writeablebitmapex]

Comment: After recherches, the answer above is the solution.

Comment: I don't see no solution and no code, just an image. What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: I don't know. I've not veryfied with current ones. But it could be that the updates already fixed that. I have not downloaded current compiled version just source instead.